# React Native - Decode HTML Entities

Tags: react-native, expo, html-entities

I have a react native expo app, and trying to decode some html entities.

I'm attempting to use the html-entities package, but it doesn't seem to work because I am mapping through a state component/array to return/render my data. Example code below. The decoding is not decoding the entities. Any examples of this working in this way for any one?

The state is being set from an api call, pulling records from the database.

```
import { decode } from "html-entities";

function Discover = async() => {
const [freeMedia, setFreeMedia] = useState([{title:She&quot; hysterical&quot;, description: test &amp; test}]);

return(
{freeMedia && freeMedia.length > 0
              ? freeMedia.map((uploads) => {
return(
<View>
<Text>{decode(uploads.title)}></Text>
<Text>{decode(uploads.description)}></Text>
</View>
)
})
: null}
)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your properties are not strings, and you're referencing freeMedia.title (undefined) instead of uploads.title:

```
import { decode } from "html-entities";

function Discover = async() => {
    const [freeMedia, setFreeMedia] = useState([{ title: "She&quot hysterical&quot", description: "test &amp test" }]);

    return(
        {freeMedia && freeMedia.length > 0
            ? freeMedia.map((uploads) => {
               return(
                   <View>
                      <Text>{decode(uploads.title, { level: "html5" })}></Text>
                      <Text>{decode(uploads.description, { level: "html5" })}></Text>
                  </View>
               )
            })
            : null}
    )
}
```

Comment: I will try to add the {level: "html5") portion, it's a typo on my end, it's correctly added in my code as uploads.title...

Comment: {decode('${uploads.videotitle}', {level: "html5"})} ... not working, it's still returning encoded @Nora

Comment: Also it should be &quot;

Comment: {`${decode(uploads.videotitle, {level: "html5"})}`}... not working either

Comment: Turns out my issue has been a data issue within my database, I have encoded data like  She&amp;quot;hysterical&amp;quto; making it difficult to decode.